# Rendering page shows right page, but the URL doesn't include action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes, action, render

Can anyone tell me why when rendering a page in rails, for example:

```
render 'controller/action'
```

the url displays

```
/domain/controller
```

instead of

```
/domain/controller/action
```

The right page is shown, but the url is just the controller.

Is this an error that I have somewhere in my app?

for example if I did:

```
render 'users/show'
```

then the users show page would be displayed, but the url would be:

```
/mydomain/users
```

instead of what I would expect:

```
/mydomain/users/show
```

Comment: I think you are a little confused, can you post your routes and controller?

Comment: sure thing, will do when i get to work.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Rails uses REST extensively for URL routing.

For eg:

When your application receives request as `GET users/1`, `routes.rb` will be referred to find out the corresponding `controller` and `action`.
Suppose, your route file contains

```
get '/users/:id', to: 'users#show'
```

Then, you request will be handle by `show` action of `users` controller.

For more information on routing in rails, refer to the [Guide.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

EDIT:

To answer your question, `why doesn't the "show" action appear in the url`,
Rails applications adhere to  REST architectural constraints, called RESTful routes which are defined using a combination of HTTP verbs and URLs to controller action

Comment: Yes, but my question is, why doesn't the "show" action appear in the url? The url is /users and not /users/show.  Sorry if I have missed the point there.

Comment: The url for show action should `/users/:id`. `/users` will render index page if you are not overriding default rails resource routes.

Comment: I am not sure if you are understanding my question.  If I click on a users_show_path link, the url is users/show.  if I render 'users/show' then the url is /users